# navigationItem.setHidesBackButton hides the arrow, but the word "Back" remains

Tags: ios, swift

I need to hide "< Back" button in the navigator controller, but for some reason

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton = true
```

only hides the arrow, the word "Back" remains:

[image]

What's the best way to hide navigation back button in iOS8?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should add this:

```
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:nil animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES animated:YES];
```

In Swift:

```
    self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems(nil, animated: true)
    self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated:true)
```

Comment: no, this doesn't work, the word "back" remains visible

Comment: @Paul I have updated my answer and tested the code. It should work now

Comment: unfortunately I don't know objC, any chance to get this in Swift?

Comment: @Paul I have converted my objc code to swift. You can check updated answer. Let me know if it works. Feel free to accept my answer if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To hide the title displayed with back button use the below code:

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@" " style:self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem.style target:nil action:nil];
```

Do remember to add this code on the previous view controller.

In swift code is as follows:

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .Plain, target: nil, action: nil)
```

Comment: Any chance to translate it into Swift? Why previous vc? How does it work exactly?

Comment: I have edited my answer for swift. Hope it helps! If it helps plz accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using following code

```
UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
   self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
```